# retrieve an image from a blob that has Base64String in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need help to get the string from a blob that has a Base64string that is uploaded and the image details saved in an mySql database by a client using a third party software. Here is the code i use to get the byte from the mysql database

```
byte[] imageByte =( byte[]) (dtImages.Rows[0]["fldData"]);
```

this is how i try to read it get into a string so that i can convert it back. It will not allow me to perform this conversion as it is a byte.

```
string image1Str = Convert.FromBase64String(imageByte);
```

How can i read the string from this to perform the conversion, once i have the string i can then save it as an image.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code.

Just replace the `connection` with your data connection, and replace `<your query here>` with the query to the BLOB object:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Collections;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.IO;

.... 

FileStream fs;                          // Writes the BLOB to a file.
BinaryWriter bw;                        // Streams the BLOB to the FileStream object.
int bufferSize = 100;                   // Size of the BLOB buffer.
byte[] outbyte = new byte[bufferSize];  // The BLOB byte[] buffer to be filled by GetBytes.
long retval;                            // The bytes returned from GetBytes.
long startIndex = 0;                    // The starting position in the BLOB output.

SqlDataReader myReader = connection.ExecuteReader(<your query here>);

while (myReader.Read())
{
    fs = new FileStream("my.bmp", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
    bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
    startIndex = 0;
    retval = myReader.GetBytes(1, startIndex, outbyte, 0, bufferSize);

    while (retval == bufferSize)
    {
         bw.Write(outbyte);
         bw.Flush();
         startIndex += bufferSize;
         retval = myReader.GetBytes(1, startIndex, outbyte, 0, bufferSize);
    }

    bw.Write(outbyte, 0, (int)retval);
    bw.Flush();
    bw.Close();
    fs.Close();
}
myReader.Close();
connection.Close();
```

Comment: Thank-you for your timely reply., but when i try to put this code            
 byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(dtImages.Rows[0]["fldData"]); 
getting a syntax error... cannot convert object to string

Comment: What are the values in your database? Can you post an example of one of the values in `dtImages.Rows[0]["fldData"]` ?

Comment: the error is a syntax error...  the blob is huge..unable to paste it

Comment: What is the column `fldData` data type in the database? Blob ?

Comment: Koby, trying it...will let you know shortly.

Comment: Ok. Good luck. Let me know the outcome.

Comment: not saving the file as an image, has a string in it , (seen in notepad+)

Comment: My example saves it as a `bmp`, what is in the database?

Comment: tried both JPG and BMP extensions, You think it has anything to do with the way it was saved ?Convert.ToBase64String ?

Comment: Well, First you need to figure out what the picture format is. Then you convert it to a file with the correct exention like I wrote in the answer...

Comment: it's definitely JPEG,

Comment: Did you try with JPEG? You wrote "ried both JPG and BMP extensions"

Comment: Tried with Jpeg.. sure it's the blob, it's converting it to a byte and that byte has to be converted back to a base64 string

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2 cents, I think you should use `Convert.ToBase64String` instead of `Convert.FromBase64String` to get what you need.

More info at MSDN about

- [Convert.FromBase64String Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Convert.ToBase64String Method (Byte[])](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524(v=vs.110).aspx)